# Does sorting time of n numbers depend on a permutation of the numbers?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Consider this problem:

> A comparison-based sorting algorithm sorts an array with `n` items. For which fraction of `n!` permutations, the number of comparisons may be `cn` where `c` is a constant?

I know the best time complexity for sorting an array with arbitrary items is `O(nlogn)` and it doesn't depend on any order, right? So, there is no fraction that leads to `cn` comparisons. Please guide me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Dukeling sorry, right, comparisons.

Comment: `O(n*log(n))` is not the best time complexity, it's the best worst-case time complexity for the comparison sort. For already sorted array you don't need `O(n*log(n))` complexity and best-case time complexity could be `O(n)`

Comment: @DAle, you mean by first checking if it is already sorted?

Comment: Yes, for example. Another example is insertion sort

Comment: It won't be a constant fraction, but you can sort any of at least 1/n! of the n! permutations with optimally cn comparisons (that is, the array that's already sorted can be sorted in cn time) (1/n! isn't the biggest fraction, it's just an example).

Comment: Consider that there is some non-constant `m` for which `m log m = n`. So if say the last `m` elements are unsorted (and the first `n-m` are sorted), you can sort those (and thus all `n` elements) using no more than `cn` comparisons. But I wouldn't want to try to figure out up to how many of the total number of permutations we can extend this.

Comment: @Dukeling it is in fact a multiple choice questions. the choices are: 1/c; 1/n; 1/2^n; none;.... so which one do you suggest? The correct answer is specified as "none!". So, I think it is not a constant fraction, or a fraction that depends only to n.

Comment: Well, I'd probably then try to work out whether 1/2^n is a reasonable answer, because it's not 1/c or 1/n.

Comment: What about array with all same values? What about radix sort? The answer for both is all permutations. Your question doesn't make sense without additional information.

Comment: BTW, radix sort can be implemented without any comparisons.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil the sorting algorithm is based on comparison, I add it to the question.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the sorting algorithm you use.

[Optimized Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) for example, compares all neighboring elements of an array and swaps them when the left element is larger then right one. This is repeated until no swaps where performed.

When you give Bubble Sort a sorted array it won't perform any swaps in the first iteration and thus sorts in O(n).

On the other hand, [Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) will take O(n log n) independent of the order of the input.

**Edit:**

To answer your question for a given sorting algorithm, might be non-trivial. Only one out of n! permutations is sorted (assuming no duplicates for simplicity). However, for the example of bubblesort you could (starting for the sorted array) swap each pair of neighboring elements. This input will take Bubblesort two iterations which is also O(n).

Comment: Good, however now the questions for which fraction of the permutations, the list is already sorted?

Comment: @Ahmad: If all list members are same the answer is all. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: The list is sorted exactly for one permutation as stated in the answer (assuming no duplicate elements).